# Polynomial of Basis Vectors Proof

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

So I'm having some trouble with a proof:

Statement:

Let $p(x)$ be a polynomial that satisfies $p(T)(b_i) = 0_V \forall i$ Where T is a linear transformation $T:V\to V$ and $b_i$ are basis vectors of V

Show this implies:

$p(T)(v) = 0_V \forall v \in V$

My thoughts so far:

$T(b_i)$ lies in V thus can be expressed as a linear combination of the basis vectors:

$T(b_i) = \alpha_1b_1 + ... +\alpha_nb_n, \alpha_i \in K$ where K is a field.

Thus the statement becomes

$p(T)(b_i) = 0_V = p(
\alpha_1b_1 + ... +\alpha_nb_n)$

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's no such thing as $p(\alpha_1b_1 + ... +\alpha_nb_n)$, because $\alpha_1b_1 + ... +\alpha_nb_n$ is a vector...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your first two lines of proof to

$v$ lies in $V$ and so can be expressed as a linear combination of the basis vectors,$$v = \alpha_1b_1 + ... +\alpha_nb_n, \alpha_i \in K.$$

Then $p(T)$ is a linear transformation and therefore $$p(T)(v)=...$$

Can you finish this proof off now?

Comment: I'm having trouble with the idea that $p(T)$ is a linear transformation, consider $p(x+y)$ its evident this isnt a linear transformation for polynomials of degree larger than 1.

Comment: I'm not sure the order in which you are studying linear algebra ideas. However if you are happy with the idea that linear transformations can be represented by matrices then the result follows easily from this representation viz. $T^2$ is represented by the square of the matrix of $T$ etc.

Comment: Thankyou so much, its all clicked. So we can represent the polynomial as one matrix acting on v?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 2):

This is implied by the fact that $p(T) $ is a linear transformation. If a linear transformation $V\to V$ evaluates to $0$ on all basis vectors, then it evaluates to $0$ on all $v\in V$ because $v$ is a linear combination of basis vectors.